# Get entity by annotation when SpringApplication startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, aop

Who has an idea how can I get all the entities that has specific annotation, for exemple `@Table` jpa's annotation, when SpringApplication startup?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide us some [MCVE] so we can see what you've tried to far, and help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use applicationContext and its method getBeansWithAnnotation()

```
@Autowired 
ApplicationContext appContext;

...

appContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(yourAnnotation.class)
```

Comment: thnx @Danila, but entities are not Spring beans

Comment: @aymenkn ok, in your question you want to get ALL instances of `@Table` class. This is equals to quyery "select e from Entity e". Why do you want to do this? What if there are 10 millions instances in your DB?